# Can i boot the server

Tags: raid, hp, central-processing-unit

Hello and good day.

I have a ml350 g4 and i have these questions:

I dont have the cpu-fan & heatsink does it need that to boot?

Does it need the chassis fan to boot?

What ram does it need?

And one other question:

I have some ibm raid controllers will they work?

Kind regards

Comment: Where did you obtain this incomplete server from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's the outline of your server's specifications](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12009_na/12009_na.html#Overview).

You need the CPU fan and heatsink in order to boot.

You need a chassis fan to boot.

The [RAM requirements are outlined here](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12009_na/12009_na.html#Memory). PC2700 DDR SDRAM @ 333MHz

You can use another controller, but it's best to stick with the server's intended storage controller. ML350 G4 systems use U320 SCSI disks, so the best RAID controllers for the model are the HP Smart Array 641 and 6400-series controllers.

Edit:

You obtained this server from some source. I would go back to that source to obtain the necessary components. It's not worth spending much money to acquire them, though. This is a very old server and may not be a good investment.

Comment: Thank you. Now i have to go on ebay and buy som parts. They are so expensive :D

Comment: @user146899 You don't need to. [You can find the *entire* server on eBay](http://r.ebay.com/4rsfCl), complete with working parts, for less than $100 US.

Comment: I do live in Norway, the shipping would be like 500 usd :)

Comment: Around 134 usd in parts....